# ASP.NET core with angular ADD token authentication not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

I have set up the Azure ADD in my project. My request from angular side is having a bearer token and i added the logic to authenticate that token but somehow its not working. Following is what i have.

Angular request -

[image]

ASP.net Core appsettings.json-

[image]

Statup.cs -

[image]
[image]

MSAL angular side configuratiion -
[image]

Comment: Can you post your MSAL / Adal js code in angular ? Check the tenant and client id it should match with appsettings and your angular code.

Comment: @Niladri It is same. I added the screenshot of MSAL fronend configuration.

Comment: If you are using V1 endpoint for authority you should use ADAL not MSAL

Comment: @Niladri I didn't get it. Where i am using V1 can you please explain me a little bit.My angular side is using MSAL as my backend.

Comment: I mean V1 version of endpoint of Azure authority